# include a javascript file within script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am investigating a way to include a JavaScript file within some script tags. I have a large JavaScript file of Google Analytics Tracking Code and I need to include it at a certain point in my code. This is my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456789']);
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/search_engines.js"></script>
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

I need to have `search_engines.js` **before** the `_trackPageview`, but the syntax is clearly invalid.

`search_engines.js` has 290 lines of this:

```
_gaq.push(
['_addOrganic','advancedsearch2.virginmedia.com','SearchQuery',true],
['_addOrganic','alltheweb','q',true],
['_addOrganic','ananzi','qt',true],
```

I was looking a jQuery's addScript, but that doesn't appear to offer what i'm looking for.

Is there a way to include the JavaScript file within my script tags?

Comment: Inside **search_engines.js** you can fire event and attach observer to it from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your script over AJAX and run the dependent code in a callback. This is trivial with jQuery:

```
$.getScript('/scripts/search_engines.js').done(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
});
```

Or, just put the whole GA code in one JS include.

Comment: Thanks, so does this effectively include the file when `getScript` is called? The `_trackPageview` call is obviously more important the including the file, so I wouldn't want there to be any occasion where the `_trackPageview` doesn't fire.

Comment: Yes - the script is loaded and immediately executed at this point. The `done` callback fires only if the JS include loads successfully. If you want to ensure this runs regardless of whether the JS include loads successfully, change `done` to `complete`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456789']);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(unescape(%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/search_engines.js"%3E%3C/script%3E)); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```